# How to assign one dataframe column's value to be the same as another column's value in r?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to run this line of code below to copy the city.output column to pm.city where it is not NA (in my sample dataframe, nothing is NA though) because city.output contains the correct city spellings.

```
resultdf <- dplyr::mutate(df, pm.city = ifelse(is.na(city.output) == FALSE, city.output, pm.city))
```

df:

```
  pm.uid pm.address                   pm.state pm.zip pm.city     city.output
   <int> <chr>                        <chr>    <chr>  <chr>       <fct>
1      1 1809 MAIN ST                 OH       63312  NORWOOD     NORWOOD
2      2 123 ELM DR                   CA       NA     BRYAN       BRYAN
3      3 8970 WOOD ST UNIT 4          LA       33333  BATEN ROUGE BATON ROUGE
4      4 4444 OAK AVE                 OH       87481  CINCINATTI  CINCINNATI
5      5 3333 HELPME DR               MT       87482  HELENA      HELENA
6      6 2342 SOMEWHERE RD            LA       45103  BATON ROUGE BATON ROUGE
```

resultdf (pm.city should be the same as city.output but it's an integer)

```
  pm.uid pm.address                   pm.state pm.zip pm.city city.output
   <int> <chr>                        <chr>    <chr>    <int> <fct>
1      1 1809 MAIN ST                 OH       63312        7 NORWOOD
2      2 123 ELM DR                   CA       NA           2 BRYAN
3      3 8970 WOOD ST UNIT 4          LA       33333        1 BATON ROUGE
4      4 4444 OAK AVE                 OH       87481        3 CINCINNATI
5      5 4444 HELPME DR               MT       87482        4 HELENA
6      6 2342 SOMEWHERE RD            LA       45103        1 BATON ROUGE
```

An integer is instead assigned to pm.city. It appears the integer is the order number of the cities when they're in alphabetical order. Prior to this, I used the dplyr left_join method to attach city.output column from another dataframe but even there, there was no row number that I supplied explicitly.

This works on my computer in r studio but not when I run it from a server. Maybe it has something to do with my version of dplyr or the factor data type under city.output? I am pretty new to r.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `city.output` is `factor` which gets coerced to integer storage values.  Instead, convert to `character` with `as.character`

```
dplyr::mutate(df, pm.city = ifelse(!is.na(city.output), as.character(city.output), pm.city))
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. This what I get for hacking through r.  Still perplexed why this code worked differently on my computer versus the server, but perhaps I did do something different so it's not a factor data type on my computer. Need to investigate that.

Comment: @Kelly it is possible that the column type is `character` in server compared to your computer or viceversa.  I would suggest to do some checks with `str(df)` to print before doing any computations

Comment: Tried it out locally again and yup, it is a <Chr> data type not <fct>.  Wish I understood why it's different there but I probably won't spend more time on it

Comment: I lied and spent more time on it. There is a setting in the Rprofile file in your R files (in library/base/R) where it has options(stringsAsFactors = TRUE) or in the case of my machine, FALSE. The two machines had different settings.

Comment: @Kelly that is only because `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` is by default from R 4.0 when you read data with read.table/read.csv or create data with `data.frame` Before  4.0, it is TRUE by default setting.  So, I assume that your R versions are different in both